# Testing Rails controller action with no direct route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building my own blog in order to learn rails3.

Need my URLs to be formatted to:

```
/blog/year/month/slug
```

So I have my routes.rb set up as this:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/blog', :to => 'post#index'
  match 'blog/:year/:month/:slug', :to => 'post#show'
  root :to => 'post#index'
...
```

Testing this via a web browser works great. The problem comes in when I want to test my PostController's `show` action method.

When I execute this test:

```
class PostControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "can get a post by slug" do
    get :show
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"post", :action=>"show"}
```

How can I write my test so I can execute the show action method in my Post controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is at least expecting there to be a `year`, `month` and `slug` parameter to be set. Your routes require that much, at least.

In your test:

```
test "can get a post by slug" do
  post = Post.create(:slug => "best-post-ever")
  get :show, :slug => post.slug, :year => Time.now.year, :month => Time.now.month
  assert_response :success
end
```

With these three parameters, the route will now be matched and your request will go through.